# Plotting dataframe columns on x-axis

Tags: python, dataframe, data-visualization, visualization

I have a dataframe with job descriptions in columns and values in rows.

Sample dataframe structure:

```
           Data Scientist   Senior Data Scientist   Data Engineer
index                   
level_1      94.366197           87.755102          93.650794       
level_2      93.239437           96.938776          95.23809
level_3      38.028169           56.122449          6.349209
```

dataframe info:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 6 entries, index to Research Analyst
Data columns (total 3 columns):
0    6 non-null object
1    6 non-null object
2    6 non-null object
dtypes: object(3)
```

I'm trying to replicate an excel output on python by having job descriptions in x-axis and create a bar chart where I can see for every job description what quantity is there for each level. Something like this:[image]

What I have so far isn't working:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
plt.style.use('ggplot')

degree_table.plot(x=['Data Scientist','Senior Data Scientist', etc.],
                  y=degree_table.index,
                  kind='bar')
```

Comment: could you share the sample raw data for the dataframe & what's the incorrect output you're getting?

Comment: I get an error that says x must be a label or position. How can I share the sample raw data on stackoverflow?

Comment: I hope in your question, 'x=['Data Scientist','Senior Data Scientist', etc.]'  the ', etc.' part is only for showing us that there are other columns? 

Have you tried with a single column?

Comment: single column didn't work. the answer given worked, thanks for the support tho!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`degree_table.T.plot(kind= 'bar')`

The 'T' there, means to transpose the matrix

Easy, try this.

Comment: I get error: TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot

Comment: In the dataframe info I see that the values are of type object , you'll have to make them of type float. 

df.astype(float).T.plot(kind = 'bar')